# How to merge data.table with potential matches in different columns?

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I am trying to merge two data tables using multiple columns using `data.table`.

One dataset has different names recorded in different columns. For example:

```
records <- data.table(name1 = c("Apple25", "Banana20", "PassionFruit97", "junk4", "sdfd", "dbfg", "sdeg", "sdgwe", "wegd"),
                      name2 = c("abxd", "dseg", "degd", "apple200", "banana5132", "PassionFroot", "jusd", "sged", "egsd"),
                      name3 = c("jefds", "sdefsd", "dgeds", "dbsed", "sdfd", "dbfg", "Apel", "BNNA", "PF"))
```

I know there these are records for three fruits - apple, banana, and passionfruit - but that information may be in any of the three columns.

I have another mapping dataset, where I have the specific names for each column in `records` linked to a standardized fruit name:

```
mapping <- data.table(std_name = c("apple", "banana", "passion fruit", "apple", "banana", "passion fruit", "apple", "banana", "passion fruit"),
                      name1 = c("Apple25", "Banana20", "PassionFruit97", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                      name2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "apple200", "banana5132", "PassionFroot", NA, NA, NA),
                      name3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Apel", "BNNA", "PF"))
```

Now, first I am interested to see which of the records are in mapping file (in this example it is 100%), and  I did this:

```
records[, mapped := tolower(name1) %in% na.omit(tolower(mapping$name1)) |
          tolower(name2) %in% na.omit(tolower(mapping$name2)) |
          tolower(name3) %in% na.omit(tolower(mapping$name3))]
```

(using tolower for scenarios with case discrepancies).

Next, I am interested in merging to `mapping` to get the standardized fruit name. One way could be to pipe merge statements:

```
records_mapped <- merge(records, mapping[, .(name1, std_name)], all.x = T, by.x = "name1", by.y = "name1") %>%
  merge(., mapping[, .(name2, std_name)], all.x = T, by.x = "name2", by.y = "name2") %>%
  merge(., mapping[, .(name3, std_name)], all.x = T, by.x = "name3", by.y = "name3")
```

But this leads to duplicate columns, which I would then have to combine. What would be an elegant way to do this in data.table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the data in long format and then perform the join.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- melt(records, measure.vars = names(records))
dt2 <- melt(mapping, id.vars = "std_name")
records_mapped <- merge(dt1, dt2, all.x = T, by = "value")
```

You can use `dcast` to get the data in wide format if needed.

Comment: `merge` method just wraps around join with `[` so that part can be simplified to `dt2[dt1, on="value"]`